# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 Integration with external hook

Tags: integration, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to setup EPL2 label printing from Netsuite. Unfortunately the company this is for is very small and they don't have much money to spend, hence they cannot buy a $1000 label printing solution.

The current system uses a linux server that then sends a file to one of the CUPS print server queues using the linux cat command. From there it goes to a Intel NetportExpress 10/100 Print Server and then to the Argox V1000+ label printer. This is via a corporate network ip address.

Instead I started looking at some cheap options:

1. Popup a browser window with content type text/plain and use a suitelet to populate that browser window with the EPL2 label printer codes. Then open a print dialog window so that the user can print to the label printer driver. This requires installation of the label printer driver for all users. Sadly I could not get this to print a label.
2. Integration from Netsuite via a Restlet to an external python application (on Linux) that can then perform the linux cat command needed to print the label. The Restlet works nice, but unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to have some sort of hook that fires when a new label custom record arrives. Therefore I have to keep on polling the Restlet from Python every 2 seconds to see if a new label is waiting to be printed. I started running this about an hour ago and so far I have made about 2500 requests without errors. My concurrency limit is 5 and I'm using 2 so that seems ok. The script does very little so I don't think there will be size limit issues. The problem is just that I wonder whether NetSuite will eventually terminate my script for doing so many requests. Not sure whether there is such a governance issue, but can't imagine that they won't eventually stop that sort of thing.
3. Use the http module to send data in an ajax type manner. This should be able to pickup when new data arrives instead of having to poll (not sure). The problem with this is that I assume I will need a static IP address which is sadly an expensive option.
4. Use Netsuite SOAP web services which might have a hook instead of polling (not sure). I think this would not be free (like Restlets) either.

So my question is whether there is a better option that I'm missing or what would you recommend. Also would I hit some sort of governance limit if I poll every 2 seconds with option 2?

Update: The polling mysteriously stopped working after 7395 requests and about 3 hours. It did not return an error that I'm aware of. The rejected requests on Integration Governance shows 0.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do the emailing thing quite a bit and it works pretty well. Volume may be an issue.

Another thing to do is just get a static IP address with something like ngrok.
ngrok runs on linux/mac/windows so you'd be able to write an app that listens on a particular port. Netsuite would send an https post to that app at (for instance) https://printing.mycompany.ngrok.io and the app would handle local printing.

I believe ngrok runs about $US60/year.

the app can verify identity with some sort of timestamp and hash so that if someone does get the https address they couldn't easily use all your paper or cause a DoS situation.

Comment: If I have a static ip and I like Python do I then still need ngrok?

Comment: depends. with a static IP you don't need ngrok for http but are you going to enable https by installing a cert from a known CA? I've never made Netsuite use a self signed certificate and I don't know if it's possible. Ngrok adds https without the cost of a certificate.

Comment: Not sure if this might help: https://noblue.co.uk/blog/netsuite-tips-installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-suitecommerce

Comment: It also talks about free certificates from Lets Encrypt

Comment: that's not relevant because you are sending from Netsuite to an http endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

We got bamboozled by a printer vender (Zebra) before we found out that we could HTTP post to most printers using PRINTER_IP:9100 and just sending the RAW ZPL/EPL as the body.

Look into: IPP enabled printers. most are these days. saves you 1000's in longrun if you have a large warehouse operation like we do

Comment: Awesome info! Sadly it does not look like the Argox printer or the Intel printer server supports Internet Printing Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling I would have NetSuite initiate the connection in an `afterSubmit` User Event script.

I've automated label printing by having NetSuite email attachments to a dedicated mail box which is monitored by a Linux server. My setup is documented here:

https://gist.github.com/michoelchaikin/80af08856144d340b335d69aa383dbe7

Comment: Initiate what kind of  a connection in an `aftersubmit` User Event script? Do you have some example code?

Comment: I think emailing would be too slow. They want to print a lot of labels and need to get them quickly.

Comment: We use this technique for a couple hundred labels a day. There is about 30 seconds wait from the record save until it comes out the printer.