Suitescript Automatically Print PDF
I have a suitelet that allows the user to scan an item's UPC code to bring up a label for that item. I would like the user to be able to scan the item and choose the "PRINT" button and have that label print directly to his hand held mobile printer.
Is there any way to do this?
I've managed to get the label to open up within the print window using inline HTML. However, this is an extra step for my user and I would like it to be printed automatically.

I created a simple node.js server (using Express) to receive an HTTP POST with the name of the printer to use, and a Base64-encoded PDF to print.
You can print to any printer the computer running node.js can see.
It's not complicated, you can take a look at the code here:
https://github.com/TexasSwede/netsuite-print

If you're using the NetSuite WMS you could use the "NSWMS Print Driver Application" to achieve this.  Your suitelet would need to create a custom record which stores the print data (commonly as ZPL) and the print driver would be configured to check for new instances of the custom record on a timeframe you select (EG: every 10 seconds).  This would require your hand held mobile printer to be networkable and shareable so that the "server" device (the computer you have the print driver running on) can submit print jobs to it.
Another option: check the following answer - you may be able to do essentially what the "Print Driver" does by using IPP directly from your suitelet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54260962/7885772
